# UuidCreate memory leak

Tags: c, windows, memory-leaks, uuid

Can anyone explain why I get a memory leak (+1.55 kB) with code below and what am I supposed to do to avoid it ?

```
void TestGuid() {
    UUID id;
    ZeroMemory(&id, sizeof(UUID));
    UuidCreate(&id);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    TestGuid(); // Memory Snapshot 1 here
    return 0; // Memory Snapshot 2 here
}
```

[image]

Comment: why you decide that you got memory leak ?

Comment: added a picture of memory snapshots as per Visual Studio

Comment: this is nothing prove. windows dlls internal can allocate additional memory in process. this is very complex process. but no memory leaks in your concrete code

Comment: this puzzles me a bit I must say. Does this mean we cannot actually trust VStudio memory monitor ? Or maybe I should change the way I try to track leaks down... Thanks anyway

Comment: no, windows process virtual space very complex structure. we can not say something about memory leaks only based on this 2 point. if say during time memory usage of your process permanent grow - this say about leak. but your concrete example say nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first call of `UuidCreate` makes some allocations. The first snapshot shows what was allocated, it seems it's related to initialization of random numbers generator:

[image]

But if you call `UuidCreate` once again, no new allocations are made. The second screenshot shows that no leaks found. So formally there are leaks but you can't fix it, and it's not a big deal - very few memory allocated.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Artem. Actually, I was concerned as I was planning to loop on UUID generation and so was afraid I would lose a few kB each time. Your test (which I should have conducted myself but my example was in fact an excerpt of an otherwise much bigger one kinda kept me away from this idea) proves it's no big deal.